# how to calculate binomial coefficents with non-integer numbers

Tags: python, r, binomial-coefficients

I know how to calculate binomial coefficients for choose(5,2), but now I want to know if there is a function that I can calculate choose(5,2.1) in python or R programming language?

Comment: I can use calculator to calculate it is equal to 10.304, so this question make sense.

Comment: What code have you written so far?  Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The combination formula for "n choose k" is given by

[image]

where `n` and `k` are whole numbers.  The generalized version for `x` and `y` in the set of real numbers is given by

[image]

where `Γ(x)` is the gamma function, a generalized form of the factorial.

To create this in Python, you can use the following:

```
import math

def generalized_binomial(x,y):
    return math.gamma(x+1) / (math.gamma(y+1) * math.gamma(x-y+1))

generalized_binomial(5,2.1)
# returns:
10.304042688575835
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the gamma function from scipy and the extended definition of the binomial coefficient.

```
>>> from scipy.special import gamma
>>> def choose(x,y):
...     return gamma(x+1)/(gamma(y+1)*gamma(x-y+1))
... 
>>> choose(5,2.1)
10.304042688575837
```

Answer (score 1):

In R you could make a function like this using `gamma`:

```
choose <- function(x, y) {
  return(gamma(x+1)/(gamma(y+1)*gamma(x-y+1)))
}

print(choose(5,2.1)) # 10.30404
```